# Pandas bar plot: Add marker to distinguish 0 and NaN

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, nan

I've got the following pandas DataFrame in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,0,np.nan,8],index=[1947,1948,1949,1950], columns=['values'])
df
      values
1947      10
1948       0
1949     NaN
1950       8
```

I want to do a bar plot using `df.plot(kind='bar')`.

How can I add a kind of marker that tells the difference between the `0` and `NaN` (and add this to the legend)?

The generic result looks like this:
[image: Bar plot of the values from the dataframe, showing 1947 as 10, 1948 as 0, 1949 as 0 and 1950 as 8]

EDIT: Well, what would be nice is something like:
[image]

I have tried to use the 'scatter' option combined with the first solution from firelynx, but still getting some errors...

Comment: This is more a data visualization question... You need to define how you want it to look, and then you can implement and get help if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to visualize nans, if you do not have any specific requirements, here is one of many ways:

```
df['isnan'] = pd.isnull(df['values'])
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Here is another way:

```
df['values'] = df['values'].fillna(-1)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

As always with pandas plotting, once you want something exactly one way, it is a lot more complicated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

markers = df[df['isnan']]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(df.index, df['values'], 0.4, align='center')       
ax1.plot(markers.index, markers, 'ro')
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticklabels(["","1947", "1948", "1949", "1950"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @user3017048 If there is any other way you want the graph to look, just post an example picture and I will try to make a graph like that for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

df = pd.DataFrame([10,0,np.nan,8],index=[1947,1948,1949,1950], columns=['values'])
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
ax.get_figure().set_facecolor('white')

nan_idx = np.where(df['values'].isnull())[0]
plt.axvspan(nan_idx-0.25, nan_idx+0.25, facecolor='white', alpha=0.5, hatch='X')

nan_legend = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='white', edgecolor='gray', hatch='X', label='nan Value')
ordinary_legend = mpatches.Patch(color='gray', label='ordinary Value')
plt.legend(handles=[nan_legend, ordinary_legend])

plt.show()
```